# sys.stdout.write() and .flush() with variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-3.6

I've been working on an RPG game and I like how the sys.stdout.write() and .flush() give it the effect of typing out the letters. But when I put a variable into to the sentence I want to type out, it doesn't type out any bit of the sentence, not even the parts I have in quotes (non variables). I was wondering if there was a way around this that didn't include me writing seperate code blocks for the variables and what's in quotes, and maybe make it type out the variable.

```
if girl1 == True:
   t="You and",girl1realname,"have found a sandy beach while looking for a 
   place of shelter. \nWhether you look left or right, the beach ranges for 
   miles.\n"
   y=girl1realname+": 'Hey, I guess I always wanted a house on the beach...I 
   think. I can't really remember.'\n"
   for char in (t):
       time.sleep(0.05)
       sys.stdout.write(char)
       sys.stdout.flush()
   time.sleep(1)
   for char in (y):
       time.sleep(0.05)
       sys.stdout.write(char)
       sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Have you run across Ren'Py yet?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm sorry, I don't know what that is

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It's not a visual game, purely run through IDE

Answer (score 1):

In your definition of `t`, the commas will make it a tuple. Iterating that should then write each chunk (`"You and"`, `girl1realname`, and `"have found..."`) at a time instead of each char in each chunk. Replace the commas with `+`.

Your definition of `y` appears to be fine.

As for reusing, you can define a function like:

```
def typeout(x):
  for char in x:
    time.sleep(0.05)
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Used like:

```
typeout(t)
time.sleep(1)
typeout(y)
```